# C# How to use KeyPressed event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void This_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A){
        player.RightM = false;
        player.LeftM = true;
    }
}
```

This if statement never actually turns out to be true.But if I use 
KeyDown's e.KeyCode == Keys.A it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `KeyPreview` Property of the Form to `true`.

`this.KeyPreview = true;`

**UPDATE:** I'm sure this will work for you

The form will handle all key events before the control with focus handles them and ensure the processing is passed to the control with focus by setting the `KeyEventArg.Handled` property to `false`. try this one:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e.KeyCode);
        e.Handled = false;
    }
```

If not worked again, put your code of initialization of the form. I hope be helpful :)

Comment: It would also be `Form1_KeyPress` (unless the form name happens to be 'This').

Comment: that this i included like
`this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(This_KeyPress);`
but still it only give me some sound like "pep" or something